# fb.login popup doesn't display additional requested permissions if popups are blocked

Tags: popup, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, facebook-authorization

I am trying to request additional permissions at the time of a facebook login using Facebook's suggested Javascript SDK. I am using the scope parameter to make the additional request as a part of the FB.login(). My chrome browser has blocked popups. When I load the page containing the FB.login and the scope parameters into my browser, Chrome blocks the automatic popup. When I then click on an html button to perform the facebook login and authorization request, the only permissions that the fb popup shows is the one for basic info. However, if I allow popups, then when I load the page, a facebook authorization popup automatically displays without the need to click on the button to launch the fb login. When this automatic popup displays, it now shows the additional permissions I included in the scope parameters. How can I get the additional permissions to display in the fb login popup when popups are blocked?

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  // Additional JS functions here
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'MY_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : 'channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional init code here
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                        // connected
                } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                        // not_authorized
                                login();
                } else {
                        // not_logged_in
                                login();
                }
        });

  };
function login() {
        FB.login(
                function(response) {
                                if (response.authResponse) {
                                // connected
                                } else {
                                // cancelled
                                }
                },
                {scope: 'email, user_birthday'}
        );
}

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button type="button" onclick="FB.login()">login</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FB.login` can not be used outside of an event handler (user initiated) due to it creating a popup when used outside of Canvas.
Instead, display a button that the user can click in order to execute `FB.login`.

The reason why your button does not ask for permissions is simply because you havent added any to the function call - you use `FB.login()` - no perms there.

Comment: ooh! Thats embarrassing. I meant to type <button type="button" onclick="login()">login</button>. Thanks for taking the time to see the errors of my ways.